# Installing plugins and using complex folder structure with child theme in WordPress

Tags: plugins, child-theme, directory, child-pages

I'm creating a new WP website based on a template, and I've created the child theme for this template. It is working without any problem. I understand the basics for a child theme as adding my `style.css`, `function.php`, etc. I need to get a better understanding on the following points:

- For plugins installation, will I install it using the child theme, or install in the parent theme?  And will it be in `/wp-content/plugins` or do I need to create another folder and add some function to it to make it work.
- If I have a file inside more than one folder in the parent theme (example `/parenttheme/includes/php/anotherfolder/example.php`) and I want to modify the `example.php` file, do I need to create and match all this structure in the child theme only?, or do I need to add more function to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general note: A lot of things in WordPress can be configured. For example the name of the `wp-content` directory. The same goes for the name of the `plugins` and `themes` directory. And both can have multiple folders (with plugins defining them).

About child themes and plugins: A plugin and a theme is (in general) pretty much the same thing. The (main) difference just is where they get loaded and which info they have for WordPress (in comment headers). And they aren't connected structurally. So a child theme has nothing to do with a plugin.

Simple rule:

> A plugin adds *functionality*. A theme adds *visual representation*.

Keeping this separated makes the theme easily exchangeable - and single functionality (each wrapped in a single plugin) as well.

About matching structure from parent > child theme: Yes, you will have to recreate that structure. But only if child theme inheritance is built into the parent theme. For e.g. a stylesheet loaded with [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_template_directory_uri/) will only load from the parent theme, while the *_stylsheet_*() counter part will use the one from the child theme. Things like `get_header()`, `get_sidebar()`, `get_footer()` or `get_template_part()` will search in the child theme first. And a child themes `functions.php` is also loaded before the parent themes `functions.php` file.

Comment: thank you, but if i want to modify a plugin, and when updating i don't lose mu modification ( same principle of child theme) what i must do ?

Comment: @AhmedNa Please don't mark something as a solution if it is none (yet). About your problem: I thought it was about modifying/overwriting functionality of a (parent) theme in a child theme? Is it now about overwriting the functionality of a plugin?

Comment: @Kiser you answered my main question, but this one came to my mind while i was working yesterday, so i think that i can ask you because it's similar to the question you answered. also i will make it as a question. Thanks